# compound interest calculator on the deposit

Tags: c#

Error on userInput `"100 12 1"` expected `101` but was `100`

What is wrong?

```
static double Calculate(string userInput)
{
    var arrString = userInput.Split(' ');
    double initialAmount = double.Parse(arrString[0]);
    int interestRate = int.Parse(arrString[1]);
    int countMonth = int.Parse(arrString[2]);

    return initialAmount * Math.Pow((1 + interestRate / 12 / 100), countMonth);
}
```

Comment: Integer division produces an integer. An interest rate is not logically an **integer**. It is a floating point quantity, so use either double or decimal.

Comment: To elaborate on Eric's point: The result of the expression `(interestRate / 1200)` is an integer because it only uses integers. `12 / 1200` expressed as an integer is `0`.

Comment: And when it comes to monetary amounts, you _may_ want to consider decimal over double.

Comment: Thanks all! I understood!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You divided an integer by an integer (`(1 + interestRate / 12 / 100)`): [this produces an integer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#integer-division).

To get the result you expect, either cast `interestRate` to an int, or parse it as a double like you did with `initialAmount`:

```cs
static double Calculate(string userInput)
{
    var arrString = userInput.Split(' ');
    double initialAmount = double.Parse(arrString[0]);
    int interestRate = double.Parse(arrString[1]);
    // either do this  ^^^^^^

    int countMonth = int.Parse(arrString[2]);

    return initialAmount * Math.Pow((1 + (double)interestRate / 12 / 100), countMonth);
    // or do this                        ^^^^^^^^
}
```